# How to fix warning: Identity file github not accessible: No such file or directory?

Tags: ssh, git, github

```
Host github.com git 
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github # I've tried also /home/freinn/.shh/github
```

There's no `/home/freinn/github` file created, have I to create it?

That's the complete warning:

```
Warning: Identity file /home/freinn/github not accessible: No such file or directory.
Hi freinn! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

[freinn@freinn ruby]$ ssh -v git@github
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/freinn/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what is working for me:

```
Host github
  User git
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The `IdentityFile` should point to the existing identify file. You can use tilde (~) which refer to a user's home directory.

Basically the error:

> Warning: Identity file /home/freinn/github not accessible: No such file or directory.

saying that this file is missing, therefore you've to create one (using `ssh-keygen`), or point to the existing DSA, ECDSA or RSA authentication identity file or use the default file (by removing or commenting out the line).

Also, in the host line (`Host github`), you can specify the host pattern such as alias which you want to use, so you can use `git@github` instead of using full host. Normally you want to use specific host entry, however you can also use a wildcard character (`*`) which will apply global settings for all hosts.

Check further information by running `man ssh_config` command.

Answer (score 1):

To get SSH authentication working for GitHub, you need to create a public/private key pair as per [GitHub's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys). The `IdentityFile` option should point at whatever file contains the private key you created while performing those instructions.

It looks like you're connecting just fine anyway* — you're seeing GitHub's successful connection message. Maybe your GitHub private key is just `~/.ssh/id_rsa`? If so, you could remove the `IdentityFile` line altogether and it'll work as expected.

If it's any help, the relevant section of my `~/.ssh/config/` looks as follows:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

…but that works only because `~/.ssh/id_rsa_github` is where I put my GitHub-specific private RSA key.

<sub>*GitHub always responds with `You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` when you successfuly `ssh` in from a shell.</sub>

Comment: It doesn't work. Same warning even entering "IdentitiesOnly yes" line

Comment: What is ‘it’? Deleting the `IdentityFile` line altogether? Copying my entry verbatim was never going to work because, as I said, it works only because `~/.ssh/id_rsa_github` is where I put my GitHub-specific private RSA key. Again, it looks like you're authenticating just fine, you *should* be able to ditch the `IdentityFile` line altogether.

Comment: I have to have the github file in /home/freinn/ and don't know why ssh search there...

Comment: Again, `ssh` is looking for *and finding* the relevant RSA key. You wouldn't get the `You've successfully authenticated…` message were that not the case. Your `IdentityFile` entry is almost certainly redundant, as `ssh` complains about it and then ultimately ignores it. If you could update your `ssh -v` output to `git@github.com` rather than `git@github`, we'd know for sure. But it's probably irrelevant, as getting rid of the `IdentityFile` line will likely stop the error message.

Comment: If I quit the line `IdentityFile` it gives `Warning: Identity file /home/freinn/github not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Something is misconfigured somewhere; `ssh` should not be looking for that file. Seeing the entirety of your `~/.ssh/config` and/or the output of `ssh -v git@github.com` (not `ssh -v github`, which is what you posted) may help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6038/discussion-between-freinn-and-iain-dawson)